# Stick last scrolled header to the top of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3G2K/1/

I have multiple divs with content, and each one has a header. I'd like to make the last header that left the viewport to be "sticky" or fixed to the top of the viewport.

I've seen a few different approaches to this, but none of them seem to work for multiple headers.

```
$('.content').scroll(function(){
    console.log('scrolling')
    $('.itemheader').each(function(){
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    console.log(top);

     if(top<25){
        $(this).addClass('stick');
     }else{
        $(this).removeClass('stick');
     }
    })
 });
```

I think there might be a conflict since each header has the same class name, and no unique identifier, so my above attempt isn't working out right.

Comment: there's a LAST function in jquery, filtering the last element in the set, you don't even need to iterate all the headings to get it. http://jsfiddle.net/R3G2K/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/iphone-like-sliding-headers/

This was exactly what I was looking for:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/header-slide.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// 1. grab a bunch of variables
var $container = $('#box');
var $headers = $container.find('h2');
var zIndex = 2;
var containerTop = $container.offset().top + parseInt($container.css('marginTop')) + parseInt($container.css('borderTopWidth'));
var $fakeHeader = $headers.filter(':first').clone();

// 2. absolute position on the h2, and fix the z-index so they increase
$headers.each(function () {
   // set position absolute, etc
   var $header = $(this), height = $header.outerHeight(), width = $header.outerWidth();

   zIndex += 2;

   $header.css({
       position: 'absolute',
       width: $header.width(),
       zIndex: zIndex
   });

   // create the white space
   var $spacer = $header.after('<div />').next();
   $spacer.css({
       height: height,
       width: width
   });
});

// 3. bind a scroll event and change the text of the take heading
$container.scroll(function () {
    $headers.each(function () {
        var $header = $(this);
        var top = $header.offset().top;

        if (top < containerTop) {
            $fakeHeader.text($header.text());
            $fakeHeader.css('zIndex', parseInt($header.css('zIndex'))+1);
        }
    });
});

// 4. initialisation
$container.wrap('<div class="box" />');
$fakeHeader.css({ zIndex: 1, position: 'absolute', width: $headers.filter(':first').width() });
$container.before($fakeHeader.text($headers.filter(':first').text()));

});
```